Using Contains in AURA for field Value
I want to use CONTAINS keyword in AURA component eg.
Let a text field having some values ..
If the text field Contains value RED logic will fire ..
Everything is written just I am not able to use CONTAINS in my Aura Component
Colours_text__c = RED .
I need CONTAINS Instead of the Equals to  to my AURA .
Can anyone please help me asap ..
Thank you in advance

CONTAINS is a Salesforce formula operator, not JavaScript. There's no equivalent Expression Function, so you must do this comparison in your controller or helper:
component.set("v.hasRed", data.Colours_Text__c.split(';').indexOf('RED') > -1);

Note that JavaScript is case-sensitive, so make sure that the field names are capitalized correctly, and the value is cased as it came from the source.
